# Allow commas and end with a dot

Tags: regex

This is what I have so far to allow only decimals to 2 decimal places

```
^(((\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*)|(\d+))(.\d+)?$
```

What I would also like is to allow commas and dots like 10,000. or 1,050.20

Comment: Your only problem is that you need to escape the dot (`.` -> `\.`). Also, if you want to be limited to two decimal places, you can replace the final `\d+` with `\d{1,2}`.

Answer (score 0):

It already matches comma-formatted numbers and floats. You are just storing the decimal precision in a separate match group.

Also, please escape the `.` character. The pattern would become:

```
(\d(?:,\d{3}|\d)*(?:\.\d+)?)
```